# how to make modal confirmation for delete action with symfony2 and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, symfony, angularjs-scope

This is my controller Symfony :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$advert = $em->getRepository('OCPlatformBundle:Advert')->find($id);
if ($advert == null) {
  throw $this->createNotFoundException("L'annonce d'id ".$id." n'existe pas.");
}
      $em->remove($advert);
      $em->flush();

      $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Annonce bien enregistrée.');

      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('oc_platform_view', array('id' => $advert->getId())));
    }


  }
```

and in twig

```
{% for advert in adverts %}
        <li>{{ advert.name|e }}</li>
<a href="{{ path('delete_route_name', {'id': advert.id }) }}">Delete</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

Please help, I dont know how to make angularJs to show modal confirmation for delete action and refresh my view page

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. You should start formatting your code properly (indentation etc...) to make it more readable for yourself and others

Comment: please read the [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in javascript:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure?')){window.location='{{ path('delete_route_name', {'id': advert.id }) }}';}">delete</a>
```